# Color not changes

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

```py
import pygame 
import random 
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1600,900))
screen.fill((100,100,200))
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type=pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
```

Comment: FYI I fixed the formatting of your code, but there was no indentation or spacing so I have no way of knowing if I preserved it or not. I'm assuming it's correct on your machine though.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

You missed to update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (draw all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type=pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    screen.fill((100,100,200))

    pygame.display.flip()
```